# Python2.7 - How to fix memory leak when OrderedDict keys are tuples

Tags: python, memory-leaks

Considering the following code

```
from collections import OrderedDict
import gc
gc.set_debug(gc.DEBUG_UNCOLLECTABLE | gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL)

def main():

    leaking = OrderedDict()
    leaking[('x', 'y')] = 4
    leaking[('z', 'w')] = 4
    return

main()
gc.collect()
print(gc.garbage)
```

one can see memory is leaking,
using `objgraph` it seems to be due to a circular reference in `OrderedDict`, which seems confirmed with this old bug in python http://bugs.python.org/issue9825 (but that is marked as closed)

using `leaking.clear()` does not seem to help

Is it a known bug ? Is there a way on my side to workaround it (The ordereddict is returned by a thirdparty library)?

I'm using python 2.7.10

Comment: The bug is marked as closed because it was fixed in [a revision](https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/56714e9c63ef/) I don't get the behaviour on my machine are you sure your python is completely up to date?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen according to the changelog of python, it was fixed in 2.7.1 , for which my version seems newer, what is your version of python ?

Comment: You've set `gc.DEBUG_SAVEALL`, which saves even objects the GC would normally be able to dispose of. It doesn't look like you have an actual leak here.

Comment: [Didn't someone already explain this to you the last time you asked about memory leaks?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38477881/python-argparse-appears-in-gc-garbage)

Comment: @user2357112 Not only that, there is obviously no circular reference in this simple piece of code.

Comment: @PaulCornelius: There are actually circular references here, inside the `OrderedDict`, but they're all collectable.

Comment: @user2357112 sorry, yes now that i re-read it is obvious, last time I thought my mistake was to have added `gc.DEBUG_COLLECTABLE` , but that DEBUG_SAVEALL was still required to get them accessible from `gc.garbage`